# How to initialize a class module

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote a class module `appWord_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)` to save a document on an SD Card as backup before closing the document.

According to the MS Site, the following code was written in a **module**

```
Dim appWord_DocumentBeforeClose As New EventClassModule
Sub Register_Event_Handler()
 Set appWord_DocumentBeforeClose.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

Here is the code in the **CLASS module**

```
Public oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)


    Dim myPath As String, myFileName As String, fileName As String  ', driveLtr As String
    myPath = "e:\stamboom\"
    If CheckDrive(Left(myPath, 1)) = True Then
        fileName = ActiveDocument.Name
        myFileName = myPath & Left(ActiveDocument.Name, Len(fileName) - 20) & " " & Format(Now, "yy-mm-dd hhmmss") & ".docm"
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=myFileName
        MsgBox "document saved on " & myPath
    Else
        MsgBox "drive E doesn't exist"
    End If
End Sub

Function CheckDrive(driveLtr As String) As Boolean
Set oFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
If oFSO.DriveExists("E") Then
    If oFSO.GetDrive("E").VolumeName = "MY SD" Then
        CheckDrive = True
    End If
    Else
    CheckDrive = False
End If
End Function
```

When I run the code in the module a VBA compile message on `Dim appWord_DocumentBeforeClose As New EventClassModule` tells me that

> the user-defined type is not defined.

Can someone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be some lack of clarity about where to use which terms/names/identifiers...

I assume the name of the class module is `EventClassModule`. At the top of that there's the declaration

```
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application
```

In the normal module, don't use the name of the event (DocumentBeforeClose), use only the name of the class module for the declaration at top of the normal module. *Plus*, assign another, different name to identify the class in this module. For example

```
Dim MyEvents As New EventClassModule
```

Then, to start the event handler's trapping:

```
Sub Register_Event_Handler()
  Set MyEvents.appWord = Word.Application
End Sub
```

`appWord_DocumentBeforeClose` will trigger automatically when a document tries to Close. If you were to add an Open or New event, these would then trigger automatically, as well, as long as the event handler is active.

In order to have the event handler trigger automatically when a document is opened the register procedure can be called from a macro named `AutoOpen`. For example

```
Sub AutoOpen()
  Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```